# Broken Ubuntu 13.10 Installation

Tags: boot, 13.10, grub2, system-installation, boot-repair

I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and shutdown my computer and now it boots to a blank screen everytime. The only thing there is a cross shaped cursor. I can boot to terminal using ctrl+alt+f1.

Boot repair did nothing (paste.ubuntu.com/6358039) and when I tried to re-install using a live CD the installation was not detected so I have no option to keep my files.

Is there anyway I can repair without losing my files in my home folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your system partition is broken. Boot on an Ubuntu 13.10 disk, choose "`Try Ubuntu`", and fix your system files this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 isn't supported natively, due to the way that unsupported releases are strung together.

Ideally, you should do-release-upgrade from the current version to the latest version, as each step will (in theory) do upgrade steps needed.

The other alternative is to do a fresh install using a currently supported release, and restore from backup.

It's generally a very bad idea to attempt to upgrade from one unsupported release to another.

Comment: You're inattentive. The question was asked on Nov 4 '13, when both 13.04 and 13.10 were being supported!

Comment: Good catch, thanks!

I only saw the "edited" date of 9 July, 2014.